# SQL query to exclude unnecessary columns

Tags: oracle

Suppose one table consist of 50 columns in oracle database, need to select more than 45 columns, but any time  select more than 45 columns by writing each individual columns name is time wasting, so need to select more than 45 columns by excluding the unnecessary columns in oracle database, How to solve the requirement??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL with [`ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm) table

```
SELECT t.table_name,
       'SELECT ' 
       || listagg(t.column_name,' ,') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY t.column_name) 
       || ' FROM ' || t.table_name as BuiltSQL
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS t
WHERE t.table_name = 'YourTableName'
  and t.column_name NOT IN('UnNecessaryCol1','col2',...)
GROUP BY t.table_name
```

This will generate an SQL code for you to use.

Comment: I don't have Oracle `RDBMS` to test it, I wrote it out of memory. Please post the error here so I'll be able to help you. @GyanBahadurTamang . Also edit the code if possible with the code you tried(you need to change the names)

Comment: yes i have change the names but still error single group function,

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: yes it generate the query but all the columns are not separated,  if you try a create function which is better helpful for me

Comment: What do you mean by not separated ?

Comment: just like , SELECT CREATEDDATA_OBJECT_IDEDITION_NAMEGENERATEDLAST_DDL_TIMEN first part output

Answer (score 1):

just write a view which selects every column you want to select

```
create view example as select [your columns] from [your table];
```

then just select the view:

```
select * from example;
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if it answered your question.

Comment: this method is correct but i won't view, i just want function with dynamic sql

Comment: views are made to select things on a frequently basis. If you need to select various numbers of columns you could use a function which returns a prepeared table.

Comment: yes i need to select various number of columns, support table contain 50 columns, then i need to select sometimes 41  columns, some times 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, and so on , so if we implement in function by excluding the unnecessary columns rather than selecting the required columns